# What is purpose of COALESCE = 0

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

There is some script that I seen where the code is as follows:

```
    AND (PC.SystemID = @SystemID OR COALESCE(@SystemID, 0) = 0)
```

I understand COALESCE chooses the first not null but not sure what the purpose would be for = 0.

Comment: The purpose of the `= 0`  is to say that the expression on the other side of the `=` must be equal to `0`.

Comment: I read that as, the value of PC.Systemid = the systemid parameter, or if the systemid parameter is null.

Comment: This is standard `0` or `NULL` default logic, considered by some an anti-pattern itself but common in systems where both null and zero are supported to trigger the _default_  functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the where clause will return true for the whole `AND`

When

- PC.SystemID = @SystemID
- OR @SystemID is NULL
- OR @SystemID = 0

so

`@SystemID IS NULL OR @SystemID = 0` is equivalent to  `COALESCE(@SystemID, 0) = 0`

Comment: `COALESCE(@SystemID, 0) = 0`  is not equivalent to `@SystemID IS NULL` - it is equivalent to `@SystemID IS NULL OR  @SystemID = 0`

Comment: i doubt that systemId is ever 0, but you are right and i corrected my answer

Comment: I think it is if @SystemID is null, give it a value of 0 for comparison purposes, otherwise, give it the non-null value that it was assigned.

Comment: we don't know enough about `@SystemId`, to speculate